Functional Form of Radon-Nikonym Derivative
Suppose I have empirical values of dQ/dP in the context of risk-neutral and real-world probabilities of asset returns. Would it be possible to fit a functional form of the derivative? I'm particularly interested in fitting Girsanov's theorem but am unsure how to proceed.

You need to estimate the $\mu$ and the $\sigma$. Surely, the easier way to do this is to take the historical log-returns of the underlying and compute their mean and standard deviation?

Thank you for the reply Jan. To contextualise, I am trying to obtain the radon-Nikodym derivative of Asset 1, and then apply this transformation onto Asset2. The idea is that if Asset 1 and 2 exhibit similar characteristics(price/return movements cointegration etc), it might be reasonable to apply the transformation onto asset2.
I cant apply the ratios as is due to the ratios exhibiting spikes at low values of x(returns) which then results in a non-smooth curve for the resulting rn density of asset 2
